# How to use Java to save a copy of the MSINFO32 System Information File

Tags: java

I am creating a program that allows me to export the System Information file on my computer (the one you get when you run MSINFO32.exe). I have scoured the internet in hopes of finding something that could help, but the closest thing I found was a forum chat from '07 saying something about using the *Jacob Library* and to run this code:

```
WinExec('C:\WINDOWS\system32\dllcache\msinfo32.exe /nfo Sys.nfo', SW_HIDE);
```

(That forum thread is [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/95760-how-to-get-system-information-of-pcwindows-os/))

So what options do I have here? I am certain there is a way to solve this issue, and I am open to anything.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the solution to my own problem. I used a cheat method of running a command-line command via Java's Runtime operation. I did the following, and sure enough it saved a copy of my Sys.nfo to the location of my Java project.

```
String command = "cmd /c start msinfo32.exe /nfo Sys.nfo";
try {
    Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```